# Trying to get a button to load another activity however the is OnClickListner crashing the app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When the register button is clicked the app should load another activity however it just crashes. Tried looking [here](http://Intent%20registerIntent%20=%20new%20Intent%20(LogInActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class);) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830966/android-why-does-my-onclicklistner-crashing-my-app) for help but I still couldn't fix it. I also tried removing 'implements View.OnClickListner' and using it how its shown in the examples and it didn't work. Also tried changing the xml file to a LinearLayout and that didn't work either. Thanks in advance!

```
public class LogInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

//user input variables
EditText emailAddressInput;
EditText passwordInput;
Button logInButton;
Button registerButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //set the layout to activity_login.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    //get user inputs and set to the variables
    emailAddressInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailAddressInput);
    passwordInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordInput);
    logInButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.logInButton);
    registerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.registerButton);

    logInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    registerButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent registerIntent = new Intent (LogInActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class);

    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.logInButton:
            break;
        case R.id.registerButton:
            startActivity(registerIntent);
            break;
    }
}
```

}

EDIT:
the logcat:

2020-04-04 16:02:10.759 12718-12718/com.example.blooddonorsystem E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.blooddonorsystem, PID: 12718
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.blooddonorsystem/com.example.blooddonorsystem.RegisterActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.blooddonorsystem.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.java:56)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7825)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7814)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

Comment: Please post the crash log instead of explaining

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Try button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {})

Comment: didnt even know that existed, I'll post it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your RegisterActivity, seems like the Spinner you are setting the adapter to is null. Make sure it has correct value, usually its an ArrayAdapter of String.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in LoginActivity but in RegisterActivity.There is a null pointer exception in RegisterActivity when you are setting adapter to a spinner.